# Why does the private beta meta have a "how to ask" message?

Tags: feature-request, meta, private-beta

The message displayed on private beta metas when you try to ask a question is the same as the message on the main site:

[image]

This doesn't reflect the type of questions asked on a meta at all (in fact, the "objective" part seems to discourage an essential type of meta-question).

Could this be removed or changed to fit the type of questions a meta needs?

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a very good point.

I think that this message is default for all private betas, be it Meta or not.

That's correct though, Meta sites are very different from their subject counterparts, and should have a different FAQ to reflect that.